# Connecting to Oracle using ADO

Tags: oracle, vba, ado

I have been given some vba code to support that connects to an Oracle database using the following syntax:

```
Dim m_dbConn As New ADODB.Connection
With m_dbConn
        .ConnectionString = "DRIVER={Oracle in oraI3CL_32};dbq=DWGBP1;Uid=;Pwd=;"
        .Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways
        .CursorLocation = adUseServer
        .Mode = adModeRead
        .IsolationLevel = adXactIsolated
        .CommandTimeout = 120
        .Open
End With
```

Normally we would use ODP.net to connect so this syntax is unfamilar to me, and any googling of oraI3CL_32 returns no results. Please can someone explain what oraI3CL_32 is, what the syntax "Oracle in oraI3CL_32" means, and whether the above relies upon having the Oracle Data Provider / tnsnames.ora preinstalled on the system? Any clarification of the difference between using ADO and ODP.net to connect (and where EZConnect fits in all this) would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You connection string looks more like an ODBC connection.

In order to use a `ADODB.Connection` your connection string should look like this one:
`Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=DWGBP1;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword`

See other examples here: [OLE DB Provider](http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=87#OLEDBProviderForOracleFromOracle)

or here [Oracle connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/)