# Connect to Oracle DB from Inno Setup?

Tags: oracle, database-connection, inno-setup, ado

I use Inno Setup to create install packages, and a new need has come up, and I have no clue. I am creating a new package that will copy Oracle files and custom made software to a server. Part of the install is the following:

Connect to the Oracle DB to verify a successful connection based on supplied SYS username and password.

- Run a few Oracle scripts.
- I already have the screens built and I have the .sql scripts.

How do I connect to an Oracle DB from Inno Setup?

Once connected, how do I run the scripts?

Is `Exec` and `ShellExec` really the best option?

I have seen examples of ADO connecting to SQL Server, but have no idea how to change that to work with Oracle.

Any help much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [[Run] & [UninstallRun] sections](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection)

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\sqlplus.EXE"; Parameters: "SYS/are_you_really_sure_to_disclose_password?@database_name @your_sql_script.sql" Description: "Run SQL Scripts"; Flags: postinstall nowait
```

Of course you could write a Pascal/Delphi scrip which connects to the Oracle database, but it might be an overkill. Most likely you would have to install Oracle drivers just for Inno Setup but not for your actual application.

And I don't think it would be a smart idea to put the `SYS` password into the Inno Setup. `SYS` is the most powerful user in Oracle, you should not hard-code its password.

Comment: Thx for your response. I have not hardcoded the SYS password in the Tool, it comes from manual input in a screen I have built. Run works well, however it does not handle error handling well... I use a script via code instead, this way I can display error codes and messages to the user. Is Exec or ShellExec the best way?

Comment: I think `ShellExec` simply runs a file (the .sql file in your case) with default program. This might be `sqlplus` or not, thus `Exec` would be the right one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect from code (Pascal Script) for better error handling, as you know, you can use ADO.

For an example how to work with ADO in Pascal Script, see:
[How to connect to MS SQL Server using Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12260493/850848)

For an example of Oracle connection string for ADO, see:
[Connecting to Oracle using ADO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24139290/850848)